# Android: ListView onItemClickListener retrieve info from database

Tags: android, listview

```
private class lvIncomeListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          (what to do here?)  
        }
    }
```

I have a ListView that is populated by items from my database. The rows in the ListView are multicolumn. The rows show DATE, TITLE, AMOUNT and CATEGORY from that particular Table that I'm fetching the data from.

My next step is to set a onItemClickListener for the ListView, and when the user clicks on of the items in the list, I want there to be a dialog popping up that shows the DATE, TITLE, AMOUNT and CATEGORY from that particular row that was clicked upon.

How is the best way to do this? Do I need to create a cursor inside the onItemClickListener or can I somehow rely on the "position" in the onItemClick?

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and inside `onItemClick` call `parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)` - it will return the `Cursor` moved to right `position`

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers weren't working would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this one as a duplicate of the newer, since you seem to have gotten your answer there, but in the future, please just edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Cursor` object is somewhere inside your `Adapter` class. Since the position is provided by your `onItemClick` method I would do the following:

```
Cursor cursor = getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
String date = cursor.getString(0);
```

Note that you need to know how your `Cursor` is queried, and what values it actually contains.

Comment: I tried with this but I accidentally made the dialog show ALL of the items in the table... I only want to show the specific row that the user clicks on?!

Comment: Oh yes noticed just now... not sure how you mean Im meant to go about here. New to android and a bit confused :/ Must I create a row in the Table for an ID that somehow is fetched when the row in the ListView is clicked on?

Comment: No, `cursor.moveToPosition` already scrolls to the correct row, you only need to use the correct indexes, like 0 could be another number in your case.

Comment: The only thing I get when a ListviewItem is clicked, I get the position of the list, 0 is the top Item and the second item is 1 and so on. What I want to achieve is to retrieve all the data from that particular row that is clicked from the database.

Comment: That's what we do in my code above.